# Can I remove the mounted drives launcher icons in Unity 2D?

Tags: launcher, unity-2d

Application's launcher icons can be removed using `gconf-editor`, but mounted drives appear on the launcher at all times (I auto-mount storage drives for my users).

In Unity 3D these can be removed by following [these instructions](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/how-to-remove-mounted-drives-from.html), is this possible in Unity2D?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unity-2D Launcher is controlled by file called `Launcher.qml`.

Whilst this method will work - changing a system file such as Launcher.qml could be overwritten by a future update.

First log out and log in using anything but unity2D(unity2D might crash if you edit that file while in use; in 12.04 Gnome will do).

Then backup Launcher.qml just in-case you need to restore the default settings.

(for 11.04 & 11.10)

```
cd /usr/share/unity-2d/launcher
sudo cp Launcher.qml Launcher.qml-backup
```

(for 12.04)

```
cd /usr/share/unity-2d/shell/launcher
sudo cp Launcher.qml Launcher.qml-backup
```

Now edit the file and find the line `items.appendModel(devices);`

```
gksudo gedit Launcher.qml
```

Now comment out the line using `/* .... */` i.e.

[image]

Save - logout and login

Comment: Nice! Really fast and clean ;P

Comment: Thanks!  This worked for me, CCSM didn't work, I guess because I'm in 2D.  One note, in 12.04 the file is in the folder /usr/share/unity-2d/shell/launcher